# Android studio installation issue in ubuntu 15.0

Tags: ubuntu

When I install the Android studio in ubuntu "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0  JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE." this error occurs how can solve?

Comment: Do you have JDK installed in your PC?

Comment: Yes I install the JDK but I don't know hoe to set ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE and path ...like  a windows..